# Excel, compare data that is not just a number

Tags: excel, compare, cells

I did not know how to word the title, but my question is this:

Cella: 220   Cellb:221-230

Is there anyway to say, highlight Cella if the value stored in Cella is not in Cellb(including boundary)?

I know how to compare cells if they have only an number in them, but I was unsure with the "-" character present.

Comment: Are the multiple-value-cell-numbers always separated the same way, by a hyphen?

Comment: Yes, simply to indicate that the value of that cell is a range.

Answer (score 0):

This formula does it for me:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",Cellb)),Cella=Cellb,AND(Cella>=LEFT(Cellb,FIND("-",Cellb)-1),Cella<=RIGHT(Cellb,FIND("-",Cellb)-1)))
```

Cella has a single value.
Cellb has either a single value to compare against, or a range of values separated by a hyphen.

It returns FALSE if the Cella value is out of the range or if it's different from the single value case.